# Returning new object, overwrite the existing one in Java

Tags: java, object

Note: This is an assignment.

Hi,

Ok I have this method that will create a supposedly union of 2 sets.

i

```
mport java.io.*;

class Set {

       public int numberOfElements;
       public String[] setElements; 
       public int maxNumberOfElements;

       // constructor for our Set class   

       public Set(int numberOfE, int setE, int maxNumberOfE) {
          this.numberOfElements    = numberOfE;
          this.setElements    = new String[setE];
          this.maxNumberOfElements = maxNumberOfE;
       }

       // Helper method to shorten/remove element of array since we're using basic array instead of ArrayList or HashSet from collection interface :(

       static String[] removeAt(int k, String[] arr) {
           final int L = arr.length;
           String[] ret = new String[L - 1];
           System.arraycopy(arr, 0, ret, 0, k);
           System.arraycopy(arr, k + 1, ret, k, L - k - 1);
           return ret; 
       }

       int findElement(String element) {
          int retval = 0;

            for ( int i = 0; i < setElements.length; i++) {

               if ( setElements[i] != null && setElements[i].equals(element) ) {
                  return retval = i;

               }
            retval = -1; 
           }

          return retval;
       }

       void add(String newValue) {
            int elem = findElement(newValue);
            if( numberOfElements < maxNumberOfElements && elem == -1 ) {
               setElements[numberOfElements] = newValue;
               numberOfElements++;
            } 
       }

       int getLength() {
           if ( setElements != null ) {
                return setElements.length;
           }
           else {
                return 0;
           }
       }

       String[] emptySet() {
          setElements = new String[0];
          return setElements;
       }


      Boolean isFull() {
           Boolean True = new Boolean(true);
           Boolean False = new Boolean(false);
          if ( setElements.length == maxNumberOfElements ){
                return True; 
          } else { return False; }
       }

      Boolean isEmpty() {
            Boolean True  = new Boolean(true);
            Boolean False = new Boolean(false);

            if ( setElements.length == 0 ) {
                return True;
            } else {  return False; }
       }

       void remove(String newValue) {

            for ( int i = 0; i < setElements.length; i++) {
               if ( setElements[i] != null && setElements[i].equals(newValue) ) {
                    setElements = removeAt(i,setElements);

               }
            }

       }   

        int isAMember(String element) {
           int retval = -1;

           for ( int i = 0; i < setElements.length; i++ ) {
                if (setElements[i] != null && setElements[i].equals(element)) {
                     return retval  = i;
                }   
           }
           return retval;
       }

       void printSet() {
            for ( int i = 0; i < setElements.length; i++) {
               if (setElements[i] != null) {
                    System.out.println("Member elements on index: "+ i +" " +   setElements[i]);
               }
            }
       }

       String[] getMember() {
            String[] tempArray = new String[setElements.length];
            for ( int i = 0; i < setElements.length; i++) {
               if(setElements[i] != null) {
                    tempArray[i] = setElements[i];
               }
            }
            return tempArray;
       }

       Set union(Set x, Set y) {
          String[] newXtemparray = new String[x.getLength()];
          String[] newYtemparray = new String[y.getLength()];
          int len = newYtemparray.length + newXtemparray.length;
          Set temp = new Set(0,len,len);
          newXtemparray = x.getMember();
          newYtemparray = x.getMember();
          for(int i = 0; i < newYtemparray.length; i++) {
               temp.add(newYtemparray[i]);
          }

          for(int j = 0; j < newXtemparray.length; j++) {
               temp.add(newXtemparray[j]);
          }
          return temp;
       }

     Set difference(Set x, Set y) {
          String[] newXtemparray = new String[x.getLength()];
          String[] newYtemparray = new String[y.getLength()];
          int len = newYtemparray.length + newXtemparray.length;
          Set temp = new Set(0,len,len);
          newXtemparray = x.getMember();
          newYtemparray = x.getMember();
          for(int i = 0; i < newXtemparray.length; i++) {
               temp.add(newYtemparray[i]);
          }

          for(int j = 0; j < newYtemparray.length; j++) {
               int retval = temp.findElement(newYtemparray[j]);
               if( retval != -1 ) {
                  temp.remove(newYtemparray[j]);
               }
          }
          return temp;
       }
}

// This is the SetDemo class that will make use of  our Set class

class SetDemo {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          //get input from keyboard
          BufferedReader keyboard;
          InputStreamReader reader;
          String temp = "";

          reader =   new InputStreamReader(System.in);
          keyboard = new BufferedReader(reader);


      try 
          {
               System.out.println("Enter string element to be added" );
               temp = keyboard.readLine( );
               System.out.println("You entered " + temp );
          }
     catch (IOException IOerr)
          {
               System.out.println("There was an error during input");
          }

     /* 
      **************************************************************************
      * Test cases for our new created Set class.
      *
      **************************************************************************
     */
     Set setA = new Set(0,10,10);
     setA.add(temp);
     setA.add("b");
     setA.add("b");
     setA.add("hello");
     setA.add("world");
     setA.add("six");
     setA.add("seven");
     setA.add("b");
     int size = setA.getLength();
     System.out.println("Set size is: " + size );
     Boolean isempty = setA.isEmpty();
     System.out.println("Set is empty? " + isempty );
     int ismember = setA.isAMember("sixb");
     System.out.println("Element sixb is member of setA? " + ismember );
     Boolean output = setA.isFull();
     System.out.println("Set is full? " + output );
     //setA.printSet();
     int index   = setA.findElement("world");
     System.out.println("Element b located on index: " + index );
     setA.remove("b");
     //setA.emptySet();
     int resize = setA.getLength();
     System.out.println("Set size is: " + resize );
     //setA.printSet();
     Set setB = new Set(0,10,10);
     setB.add("b");
     setB.add("z");
     setB.add("x");
     setB.add("y");
     Set setC = setA.union(setB,setA);
     System.out.println("Elements of setA");
     setA.printSet();
     System.out.println("Union of setA and setB");
     setC.printSet();
     }
}
```

The union method works a sense that somehow I can call another method on it but it doesn't do the job, i supposedly would create and union of all elements of setA and setB but it only return element of setB. Sample output follows:

```
java SetDemo
Enter string element to be added
hello
You entered hello
Set size is: 10
Set is empty? false
Element sixb is member of setA? -1
Set is full? true
Element b located on index: 2
Set size is: 9
Elements of setA
Member elements on index: 0 hello
Member elements on index: 1 world
Member elements on index: 2 six
Member elements on index: 3 seven
Union of setA and setB
Member elements on index: 0 b
Member elements on index: 1 z
Member elements on index: 2 x
Member elements on index: 3 y
```

thanks,
lupin

Comment: This is what's commonly known as a wall of code. Most people won't bother wading through it to help you. If you shrink it enough to show the essence of your problem and not much more, you'll stand a better chance of getting help.

Answer (score 2):

In `union()`, you have a typo here:

```
newYtemparray = x.getMember();
```

should be

```
newYtemparray = y.getMember();
```

Comment: +1 Exactly, this means that he was doing the union of X with X.